# Virtual Machine Snapshot revert issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-workstation, virtualization, active-directory, snapshot

After reverting to an older snapshot, Windows Server 2008 VM running on VMWare gives me the following error when I tried to login:

> The trust relationship between this workstation and primary domain failed

To resolve this I have to remove the machine from domain controller and add it again.
What is causing this problem? How to prevent this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The snapshot version of the VM is old and the computer account's password is now mismatched with the domain database. The best way to avoid this is to not keep snapshots for a long period of time. The best practice is to try and remove snapshots after a short period of time, allowing the delta files to be merged with the original vmdk. In addition to losing sync with the domain, another downside of keeping snapshots for a long time is degraded VM performance, due to buildup of multiple deltas.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that long lived VMware snaps are a bad idea in general - they not only degrade performance, they will eventually eat up all available space and getting rid of them can be troublesome.